# how do I install pygame for python 3.9 for mac?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pygame

I do pip install pygame and it says that I have it installed, but for python 2.7 so I do pip3 install pygame and it doesn't work, instead it gives some a bunch of errors. If you have an answer please help!

Comment: What error did you get? Please specify

Comment: See [Python3, Macs and Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile#Python3,%20Macs%20and%20Pygame)

Answer (score 1):

When installing it I would make sure you are first running python 3 in your terminal or command line before putting in your install command. I know there is a dev version out.

```
pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

If you're on mac you might try pip3 instead of just pip.

Comment: You can also look at the available versions by putting  -pip install pygame==

Comment: i did pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6 and it installed it for python 2

Comment: I would try pip3 install pygame==2.0.0.dev6 if you haven't already